# How do I make the Surface Book's trackpad work without a delay?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, microsoft-surface

I am a mac user and am used to quickly using the trackpad after typing.

It seems that if any key is pressed, the trackpad is disabled for .5 to 1 seconds.

Is there any way I can reduce or eliminate this delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Start menu and select Settings > Devices > Mouse & Touchpad (alternatively, you should be able to search Mouse and touchpad and find the same thing).  There should be a setting to adjust the delay/turn it off.

Also turning off the "Use a two finger pinch to zoom" setting may help, but you will lose this functionality.

The reason for the delay is because it is trying to detect accidental touches so it can ignore them.

Comment: This is great. The floor manager at the MSFT store in NYC didn't know this. :)

Comment: Glad to help :)